# Consultar varias tablas para obtener un conjunto de resultados

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo 4 tablas:

Tabla 1 - Usuarios:

- código_usuario(PK)
- nombre
- apellido
- fecha_nacimiento
- sexo_usuario
- dirección_domicilio
- estado_civil
- numero_celular
- país_residencia
- foto_usuario

Tabla 2 - Usuarios Cuentas:

- código_cuenta(PK)
- código_usuario(FK)
- correo_electrónico
- clave_cuenta

Tabla 3 - Eventos:

- código_evento(PK)
- fecha_evento
- hora_evento
- lugar_evento

Tabla 4 - EventosParticipantes:

- código_evento_participante(PK)
- código_evento(FK)
- código_usuario(FK)

Lo que deseo obtener es la foto, el nombre, apellido y el correo electrónico de las personas que participaron de un determinado evento, explico, en la tabla 3, como su nombre indica, ahí se guardan puro registros de eventos que se realizaron y en la tabla 4 se guarda quienes participaron de ese evento, teniendo como llaves foráneas el código del evento y código de usuario, d esa manera poder saber que usuarios participaron de que evento. Una ayuda con esto por favor creo que sera una consulta grande y no me doy cuenta como hacerla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se como está armada la estructura de la tabla, ya que lo que pones no indica desde donde hacia donde están armadas las referencias, pero si mal no entiendo, con un join sencillo podrías hacerlo.

```
select Usuarios.foto_usuario, Usuarios.nombre, Usuarios.apellido, UsuariosCuentas.correo_electronico
from Usuarios
inner join EventosParticipantes on Usuarios.codigo_usuario = EventosParticipantes.codigo_usuario
inner join UsuariosCuentas on Usuarios.codigo_usuario = UsuariosCuentas.código_usuario
where EventosParticipantes.código_evento_participante = elcodigoquenecesites
```

Seguramente tengas que ajustarlo, pero a primera vista serviría.

Comment: No funciona como espero, ya que si yo creo dos registros en la tabla `Eventos` y luego solo a 1 de ellos le asigno quienes son los participantes de ese evento, la consulta devuelve los mismos participantes para ambos registros de eventos y no debería ser así, si yo agrego 5 participantes a un determinado evento la consulta debería devolver quienes son los 5 participantes de ese evento, y si yo hago la consulta para los demás registros pues no debería mostrar participantes ya que no se agrego participantes.

Comment: @Leonidas edité mi respuesta, chequeala por favor. Recordá también que no siempre te van a dar la ayuda específica sobre lo que necesitás y vas a tener que trabajar sobre eso. No todas las respuestas sirven en todos los ambientes, si no que también se requiere un trabajo de tu parte.

Comment: Sale error, dice que la tabla `EventosParticipantes` no es única, por lo que veo la consulta no tiene una clausula para `WHERE` y creo que eso hace falta para poder obtener los participantes de un DETERMINADO EVENTO, se tendria que obtener a los participantes de eventos en base a la llave primaria de la tabla `EVENTOS`(código_evento). Aun asi gracias por las sugerencias.

Comment: El error es porque incluí (por error) un doble join. Agregue el where.

Comment: Ahora si, perfecto, gracias.

Comment: @Leonidas muchas gracias por puntuar la respuesta. Te recuerdo que el objetivo de StackOverflow no es resolver dudas puntuales, aunque muchas veces así sea, si no mas bien dirigir a la persona que pregunta hacia el camino correcto para resolver cierta cuestión. El agregado de un where a una query es una cosa básica que no requiere un nivel técnico avanzado y que podrías haberlo agregado en base a mi respuesta original.